# Выдвижное меню JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему скрипт не работает?

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("activatemenu").click(function(){ 

    $("topmenu").animate({

      height:'10rem'    

    });
  });


</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="activatemenu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    <p class="mobiletext">Menu</p>
</div>
```

Блок меню:

```
<div class="topmenu"></div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на div.activatemenu размер .topmenu становился 10rem
Объясните человеку что только начал изучать JS, заранее благодарен c:

Comment: 1) можно и css приложить. 2) весь код (js html css) можно разместить в сниппет, чтоб хоть как-то привести [mcve] 3) у вас в js не хватает еще одной `});` - это так задумано?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на JSFiddle мало?

Comment: ссылки на другие источники могут устареть, удалится, быть недоступны. И еще к тому же надо туда перейти, что-то открыть. На ruSO специально сделаны сниппеты (во всяком случае для js,css,html) чтобы можно было поместить код непосредственно туда. ссылку на jsfiddle можно как дополнение приложить к коду, уже размещенному тут.

Comment: опишите хотя бы как должно быть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка синтаксиса jQuery. Попробуйте поставить перед activatemenu и topmenu точки, как в css, чтобы указать, что это классы.

Comment: Egor, разве где-то не проставлены точки?
В упор не вижу ошибки :c

Comment: @user234223, я вернул первоначальную версию вопроса. Если у тебя появился новый вопрос задай его отдельно.

Comment: @Grundy только вот соль в том, что я задавал новый - и его тупо изменило автоматически

Comment: @user234223, это невозможно. Попробуй задать еще раз. [Вот по этой ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @user234223 Пожалуйста, опишите развернуто, что именно у вас произошло с вашим вопросом в публикации на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @user234223, Николас [нашёл причину вашей проблемы](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37571850#37571850).